# Best and Worst options in Gale Shapley algorithm for an agent

Tags: matching

Please consider the figure below. I have to find the best and worst options for W. From the preference list of W, the best option for W is D but there is no matching of W with D in all the 6 options. Thus option 1 is the best option in the context of W because A is the second preferred element of W.

Now C is the worse preferred option of W. Thus option 5 & 6 are the worse options of W. 
X (worst : 4, Best:2)
Y (Worst : 6, Best:2)
Z (Worst:  6,   Best: 1,2 &3)

[image: Best and Worst options for an Agent]

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

Gale-Shapley can run two (symmetric) ways: Men propose to women (men get their most desirable mate in any stable matching) or the other way around.